# PHP isset() method not returning true

Tags: php, codeigniter, isset

At the model of MVC pattern of codeigniter, I make some codes that is same at below.

```
function getBoardNum($option){
    foreach($option as $key=>$content){
        $this->db->where($key,$content);
        //echo "$key $content";
    }
    if(isset($this->db->get('parsing_tb')->row()->num)){
        $num = $this->db->get('parsing_tb')->row()->num;
        return $num;
    } else {
          return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is the `isset` at the `if` condition seems to not work.
To find out what is wrong, I used `var_dump` and such like confirming the $option data. But everything is okay...

Please let me know what is wrong! Thank you for reading.

Comment: `isset()` is intended to find out if a variable or property has been set, which sort of loos like your intent. What result are you getting? Does `isset()` return `false` when you know that the property `num` exists?

Comment: And what is the `var_dump` of `this->db->get('parsing_tb')->row()->num`?

Comment: `$this->db->get('parsing_tb')->row()` might be returning an object with properties including num. Even if it's null, so you might be better off checking `if(empty($this->db->get('parsing_tb')->row()->num))` maybe?

Comment: do var_dump to `$this->db->get('parsing_tb')->row()->num` and let me know

Comment: Oh.. It is problem of `this->db->get('parsing_tb')->row()->num`. Obviously `isset` is worked well. I'm sorry. I should have thought more. Do i have to delete posts?

Answer (score 0):

You should use isset to check if some variable is initialized - that means you check if it has any value.
even this case will yield TRUE:

```
$var = "";
if( isset( $var )){
  echo TRUE;
}
```

In your code it looks like you are first trying to initialize it and assign some value to it and you use isset. You should use a different method for whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Idk why isset() is not working, but you can try this instead :

```
//...

$query = $this->db->get('parsing_tb');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
  $num = $this->db->get('parsing_tb')->row()->num;
  return $num;
}
else
  return false;
```